# How pandas calculate sem()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

First import pandas and create Series with perfect normal distribution:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[5 for x in range(5)], [4 for x in range(4)], [3 for x in range(3)],
       [2 for x in range(2)], [1 for x in range(1)], [2 for x in range(2)],
       [3 for x in range(3)], [4 for x in range(4)], [5 for x in range(5)]]

lst = [item for sublists in lst for item in sublists]

series = pd.Series(lst)
```

Let's check, that distribution is normal:

```
print(round(sum(series - series.mean()) / series.count(), 1) == 0)
# if distribution is normal we'll see True
```

Now let's print sem() for universe:

```
print(series.sem(ddof=0))
# 0.21619987017
```

Now for sample:

```
print(series.sem()) # ddof=1
# 0.220026713637
```

But I can't understand how pandas calculate standard error of the mean if it work with universe. Is it use

```
se_x = sd_x / sqrt(len(x))
```

or create samples? If it creates samples, how much and how I can set count of them?

And how pandas calculate sem for sample if count < 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas generates `sem` method dynamically](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L5849)

```
    cls.sem = _make_stat_function_ddof(
        cls, 'sem', name, name2, axis_descr,
        "Return unbiased standard error of the mean over requested "
        "axis.\n\nNormalized by N-1 by default. This can be changed "
        "using the ddof argument",
        nanops.nansem)
```

[where `nanops.nansem()` is](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/nanops.py#L420):

```
@disallow('M8', 'm8')
def nansem(values, axis=None, skipna=True, ddof=1):
    var = nanvar(values, axis, skipna, ddof=ddof)

    mask = isnull(values)
    if not is_float_dtype(values.dtype):
        values = values.astype('f8')
    count, _ = _get_counts_nanvar(mask, axis, ddof, values.dtype)
    var = nanvar(values, axis, skipna, ddof=ddof)

    return np.sqrt(var) / np.sqrt(count)
```

You may also want to check methods available in [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) module